# Set PHP date as today's date in jQuery Full Calendar

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

I am working on full calendar plugins of jQuery. I've to set today's date of full calendar according to dynamic time zone. I've today's date in PHP variable. How to set the today's date from PHP variable in full calendar. I'd tried with option of `gotoDate` but its not working.

Please find below code:-

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
            gotoDate : <?php echo $startdate; ?>,
            dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view){
                $(".fc-state-highlight").removeClass("fc-state-highlight");
                $("td[data-date="+date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')+"]").addClass("fc-state-highlight");
            },
            eventRender: function(event, element, view){
                if(event.start._d.getMonth() !== $("#calendar").fullCalendar("getDate")._d.getMonth()){
                    return false;
                }
            },
            viewRender: function(view, element){
                $(".fc-other-month").html("");
            },
            windowResize: function(view) {
                if($(window).width() < 514){
                    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("changeView", "basicDay");
                }else{
                    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("changeView", "month");
                }
            }
        });
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

"gotoDate" is a **method** not an **option**. You can't specify it in the initialisation options like that.

In order to set the date that is displayed when the calendar loads, what you need is "defaultDate" (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/defaultDate/)

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
        defaultDate : <?php echo $startdate; ?>,
```

You should ensure that `$startdate` is in `YYYY-MM-DD` format to be certain that there's no ambiguity over the information being given to fullCalendar.

N.B. "gotoDate" is intended to be used *after* the calendar is initialised, if you need to set the current date manually based on some event outside the scope of the calendar control. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/gotoDate/ for usage instructions.

Comment: Thanks very much for your Answer. I got it done with an option of now in full calendar.

Comment: using "now" is not quite the same as setting the current date for display on the calendar. "now" merely highlights the date you give it as being "today" on the calendar. It doesn't control the date that the calendar actually displays. Since you were originally trying to use "gotoDate" I assumed you wanted to control the date that was displayed by the calendar when it first loads, not trying to tell it which day to use as "today".

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :D

```
//seting current date php
$today = date("Y-m-d");

//seting current date in js fullcalendar

defaultDate:   <?php echo "'" . $today. "'"; ?>, //yyyy+"-"+mm+"-"+dd,  >jsformat<


//example
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

                defaultDate:   <?php echo "'" . $today . "'"; ?>,
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/gotoDate/), you have to create first an MomentJS object. So you have to set the php variable in to an Moment object like this:

```
var date = $.fullCalendar.moment('2014-05-01'); //This is the format Y-m-d

var date = $.fullCalendar.moment('<?php echo $startdate; ?>');
```

After you created your object, you set the js variable `date` in the goToDate attribute:

```
gotoDate: date
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I'd tried this solution and it is not working. I'd tried like this. var date = $.fullCalendar.moment("2017-06-17"); and then writes this. gotoDate : date. But its not working

Comment: @mohammashoaibnagori What error do you get in the console? Do you have embedded the MomentJS library from https://momentjs.com/?

Comment: yes moment.js is included. I ma not getting in error in console. It is not setting the time 17 as todays date

Comment: @mohammashoaibnagori Can you show us your updated code?

Comment: Thanks very much for your help bro. I got the working solution with an option of now in full calendar. I'd converted the date as mentioned above and instead of gotoDate i'd used now option.

Comment: "gotoDate" is a method not an option. You can't specify it in the initialisation options like that. And there's no need to convert an ISO string to a moment like that, fullCalendar will recognise it and do that for you. See my answer.